# How do I create a more dynamic Scrapy Spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Python and Scrapy and I am working on scraping a CMS that could have up to 16 containers of up to 10 elements I would like to scrape. Some websites don't enable all 10 elements and may have 5. What are some tips and guidance on a loop to dynamically check each container to check if it's 5 to 9, 10 elements and be able to correctly adjust the XPath for the right yield location?

If I have the Scrapy script for the 10 items and 9 items appear, everything is moved up into the wrong location which is why I'd like to incorporate some conditionals for the XPath, same for the 5 elements

I have some code that counts the number of dl, dd, and dt elements so that I could dynamically update the XPath which are basically

```
countdlnodes = len(response.xpath(xpath_for_dl))
countdtnodes = len(response.xpath(xpath_for_dt))
```

Inside the parse function I have:

```
for dl_iterator in range (1, countdlnodes+1):
                    dlgrab = '/dl' + '[' + str(dl_iterator) + ']'

                    for dt_iterator in range(1, countdtnodes+1): #checking dt in each of the dl's

                        dtgrab1 = '/dt' + '[' +str(dt_iterator) + ']' #/dt[]
                        ddgrab = '/dd' + '[' +str(dt_iterator) + ']' #/dd[]


                        grabDTxpath = titleurlxpath + '/div/div[@class= "description"]'+ dlgrab + dtgrab1 + '/text()'


                        getdesctext = titleurlxpath + '/div/div[@class= "description"]' + dlgrab + ddgrab + '/text()'


                        #checkresp = response.xpath('//dl[1]/dt[1]/text()').get()
                        checkresp = response.xpath(grabDTxpath).get()

                        if checkresp == "text1:":
                            text1_SELECTOR = getdesctext #'/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()'
                        elif checkresp == "text2:":
                            text2_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text3:":
                            text3_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text4:":
                            text4_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text5:":
                            text5_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text6:":
                            text6_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text7:":
                            text7_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text8:":
                            text8_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text9:":
                            text9_SELECTOR = getdesctext
                        elif checkresp == "text10":
                            text10_SELECTOR = getdesctext
```

One Page could look like this

```
 <div class="details">
    <dl>
         <dt>Header</dt> 
             <dd>Description</dd>
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="name1">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="name2">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Second Page could look like this (a pair of dt and dd elements were removed inside inside the name1 class:

```
 <div class="details">
    <dl>
         <dt>Header</dt> 
             <dd>Description</dd>
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="name1">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="name2">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Third page could look like this

```
 <div class="details">

    <dl class="name1">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd> 
         <dt></dt> 
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class="name2">
         <dt></dt>
             <dd></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `<dt>` content for your logic? Read everything into dictionary (using `<dt>` as keys and next find correct values.